# two arrays that have matching content bind links from one to the other

Tags: vue.js

I have 2 sets of data coming in from a Ajax request. One set only contains titles I own. The other set contains all the titles that exists plus their URL. What I am trying to do is bind the first set to URLs found in the 2nd set.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    todos: [
  { text: "Learn JavaScript" },
      { text: "Learn Vue" },
      { text: "Play around in JSFiddle"}

    ],
    myURLs: [
    
     { text: "Learn JavaScript", url:"http://google.com" },
      { text: "Learn Vue", url:"http://google1.com" },
      { text: "Play around in JSFiddle", url:"http://google2.com"  },
      { text: "Build something awesome",url:"http://google3.com" }
      
      ]
  

  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h2>My Title + Hyperlinks:</h2>
  <ol>
    <li v-for="todo in todos">
 
         <a v-bind:href="myURLs.url">{{ todo.text }}</a> 
        
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `computed` to create a dictionary

```
  computed: {
      myUrlDict() {
          return this.myURLs.reduce((a, c) => {
              a[c.text] = c.url
              return a
          }, {})
      }
  }
```

then use it in template

```
   <li v-for="todo in todos">
         <a v-bind:href="myUrlDict[todo.text]" v-if="myUrlDict[todo.text]">{{ todo.text }}</a> 
    </li>
```

Comment: coo!l, so its going to auto-search for those links if they exists in the other array.